# How to focus Div after window.scroll - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got 2 components `A` & `B`, when the `next` button is clicked it moves to `B` component with Scrolling effects.

Issue is, After moving the `B` component content is not focused on `top` instead it is focused on the centre.

Please refer this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-xugneo to replicate the issue

Below is the login for moving one component to another

```
  useEffect(() => {
    scrollToComponent(refs.current[step]);
  }, [step]);
```

`A component`

```
  return (
    <div tabIndex={0} id="a" className="step" ref={props.domRef}>
      <h1>Component A</h1>
      <button className="next" onClick={props.toNext}>
        NEXT
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

`B Component`

```
 <div tabIndex={1} id="b" className="step" ref={props.domRef}>
      <button className="prev" onClick={props.toPrev}>
        PREV
      </button>
      <h1>Component B</h1>
....
```

I tried the below step, but not working. I'm stuck & unable to proceed further. Please help

```
document.getElementById('b')?.focus();
```

Refer this stackblitz project